# Authorization SMTP in emailsender

Tags: c#, smtp

I need to write a class sending emails for authorization proccess in registration in the application. I think that my code is okay, but during compilation program always throw an exception "SMTP 5.7.0". I read, that it is related with security settings in google account, but when I'm trying to change that, google shows on official gmail website a message:
"To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password."

How do you sending your mails from google accounts in your apps right now? I was trying to change email to onet, but it also does not work.

```
    public static class EmailSender
    {
        public static bool Send
            (string from, string to, string subject, string name, string body, string fromPass)
        {
            byte[] encodedByteFrom = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(from);
            from = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedByteFrom);

            byte[] encoddedByteTo = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(to);
            to = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encoddedByteTo);

            byte[] encodedByteSubject = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(subject);
            subject = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedByteSubject);

            byte[] encodedByteName = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(name);
            name = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedByteName);

            byte[] encodedByteBody = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(body);
            body = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedByteBody);

            byte[] encodedByteFromPass = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fromPass);
            fromPass = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedByteFromPass);

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            message.From = new MailAddress(from);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, fromPass);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show
                            (ex.Message, "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may have a TLS issue.  What version of Net are you using?  What operating System?  What type of machine?  You are using NetworkCredential and port 587 which is correct and EnableSsl = true.  You need to use TLS 1.2 or 1.3 which should automatically be set with latest net version.

Comment: Try using port 465

Comment: @jdweng .NET version = 4.5, OS = win10, TLS = 1.3, everything is ok, I always download VS updates

Comment: @Charlieface When I use port 465 program throws an exception "Failure sending mail"

Comment: Why old Net?   Net 4.5 probably will not work with TLS 1.3.  Encryption will not work,  Need at least Net 4.7.2.

Comment: Typing error, I have a last stable version with VS 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an Application Password which has 16 characters as described here:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB

Then use it here:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, YourApplicationPassword);
```

I solved the same problem with Yandex. Go to your Yandex Mail -> All Settings -> Security Settings. Then click App Passwords link. Click create button and use that password.

If you don't have to use Gmail you can try that with a Yandex account. Because as I know Gmail has some new security limitations.

Comment: The user is not using an APP.  The user is properly using NetworkCredential.

Comment: I faced the same issue several days before and because of some new security limitations the only way is that. You create an App Password and use it while creating NetworkCredential. But I did this with Yandex so I will edit my answer.

Comment: May be somebody should ask GMAIL is the Network Credential have to change to use longer password.  Network Credentials is using a Window Credential using the users login.  I wonder if this issue has anything to do with a Window Hello.

Comment: Must password be exactly 16 characters? My current mail pass is 22 and it does not work

Comment: You will use App Password not your mail password.

Comment: Open the link in my answer and follow the steps of "Create and use app passwords". While creating your password choose Other (Special Name) under the Application Selection dropdown. Then click Create button. My page is not in English so some words may be different than I said.

Comment: @OrkunBekar It works!!! Thank you very much, man! I think your answer is going to be helpful not only for me ;)

Comment: You are welcome :) if that solved your problem mark it as answer please